# CodeIgniter put email in a global function

Tags: codeigniter, email

I can send an email from within a controller with the example in the CodeIgniter documentation. I was wondering how I would put the email code on a global functions page so I have access to it all over with a simple function call.

// in controller

```
emailTest($to, $subject, $message);
```

// on a global functions page

```
function emailTest($to, $subject, $message) {

    $this->load->library('email');

    $this->email->from('my@example.com', 'My Name');
    $this->email->to($to); 
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message);    

    $this->email->send();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a [helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html) and just load it up when you need it.

```
$this->load->helper('email');
send_email($to, $subject, $message);
```

---

Edit: Since you want to use the inbuilt email functionality, [libraries](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html) would be a better bet:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Library {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function send_email($to, $subject, $msg)
    {
        $this->CI->load->library('email');

        $this->CI->email->from('my@example.com', 'My Name');
        $this->CI->email->to($to); 
        $this->CI->email->subject($subject);
        $this->CI->email->message($message);    

        $this->CI->email->send();
    }

}
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
$this->load->library('my_library');

$this->my_library->send_email('test@example.com', 'RE: test message','cool message');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is exactly what I want! Only one problem, when I try your provided code I get `Message: Undefined variable: CI`, any ideas?

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake, sorry. I updated the answer. Because we're instantiating CI in the constructor, we need to do so via `$this->CI =& get_instance()` then call it like `$this->CI->email->send();` in the controller methods.